# How do you create a Collection of GenuineVariableDescriptors?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to implement my own `MoveListFactory` and don't know how to access / create the variable descriptors for the move I want to instantiate. The `createMoveList` method (from the `MoveListFactory` interface) takes a single argument of an instance of my `Solution` class. From this I can access all the planning variables that I need to create a `ChainSwapMove`. What I'm unsure about is how to create the first argument that the `ChainSwapMove` constructor requires (e.g. the `Collection<GenuineVariableDescriptor>`). The example in the documentation doesn't shed any light on this process since the custom move used in the NQueens example doesn't require this Collection of `GenuineVariableDescriptors`. I've not come across any examples of how someone can access these from only the information contained in a `Solution` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything ending with `*Descriptor` is **very internal API**, not the kind of classes I want users to be using. The docs presume you build your own move (which is difficult indeed to build a valid move on chained variables that leaves the chain in a valid state).

That being said, here's a clue: `InnerScoreDirector.getSolutionDescriptor().getEntityDescripor(MyCustomer.class).getVariableDescriptor("myPreviousStandstill")` ...

Comment: `InnerScoreDirector` is just an Interface. How would I get a concrete instance of it to start the method chain you suggest (from only a Solution)? 

I'd previously got a handle on a `SolutionDescriptor` by doing  `SolutionDescriptor sd = new SolutionDescriptor(OptaInstance.class)` then in my actual moves construction used its `findGenuineVariableDescriptor` method, but at that point there'd always be a NullPointerException. It was as if it hadn't been initialised with the entities that `OptaInstance` contains.

Comment: Hmm, MoveListFactory doesn't get the ScoreDirector indeed. It really presumes you're using your own custom moves, instead of reusing the generic ones. `MoveIteractorFactory` does get the ScoreDirector, which can be cast to `InnerScoreDirector` to follow the white rabbit down the dangerous rabbit hole...

Comment: Creating a second SolutionDescriptor instance is a bad idea: too much code relies on equals checks that there's only 1 variable descriptor per variable.